# Delete directory and create new one with same name and permissions

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, delete

I want to delete a directory with its contents recursively, and then re-create it with the same name and permissions. That directory may or may not be created or owned by me earlier before delete, but I am sure I wouldn't touch any folder created by Root, just the folders created/owned by Users same level as me.

I have the command to recursively delete the directory with all its contents:

```
rm -rf path/to/somefolder 2> /dev/null
## OR ##
rm -rf /some/path/.* 2> /dev/null && rm -rf /some/path 2> /dev/null
```

But how can I get the permissions before deletions and then reapply them to the newly created directory?

Comment: Why not leave the directory alone and just delete its contents?

Comment: Exactly, can you explain what your final objective is here? If we know why you want this, we might be able to offer an alternative and we will certainly be able to help better since we will understand the aim. By the way, your second command isn't the same since `rm -rf /some/path/.*` wouldn't delete hidden files (e.g. `/some/path/foo` would remain) and, anyway, the second command would delete everything in any case, so it's pointless to run the first part before.

Comment: Oh, and please tell us what operating system you are using so we know what tools you have available.

Comment: *"That directory may or may not be created or owned by me earlier before delete, but I am sure I wouldn't touch any folder created by Root, just the folders created/owned by Users same level as me."*  Firstly, there is no such thing as user "levels."  Also, it's unclear if you're talking about the permissions on subdirectories, or on the first directory you name (the one you're going to recreate).  If you don't have write permissions on the parent directory, you won't be able to delete *or* recreate the target dir, even if you have full permissions on the target dir.

Comment: Probably what you want here is `cd path/to/somefolder && find . -delete` which wipes all contents of somefolder but leaves somefolder itself in place.  But that's not exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @Wildcard why would you `cd` instead of doing `find path/to/somefolder -mindepth 2 -delete`?

Comment: @terdon mindepth isn't POSIX, not as portable.

Comment: @Wildcard neither is `-delete`. As far as I know, both are GNU extensions, so you'd need `cd path/to/somefolder && find . -exec rm {} +` for portability anyway.

Comment: @terdon, fair point, I'll start preferring mindepth in the future.  (The rm approach wouldn't work for directories, would need more flags.)